# Is it possible to show part of a view inside a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a view with a table with some data from the database, this is a full view with it's layout and everything.

My intention is to include in the main index page only the table of that view (and not include the layout, title, etc.)

This means `RenderPartial` is not working since it renders the full page.

Is there any way to make the table a section and render in the index only that section or something similar?

Comment: separate the shared portion into a partial and call the partial in both views that require it

Comment: can you add some of your code we can see how you're using `RenderPartial`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way

Comment: @GregH That was simpler than I expected, I feel a bit stupid now

Answer (score 2):

First create a partialView with your table

```
@model ChildViewModel
//Generate your table with the data of ChildViewModel
```

In your initalView containing table and in the index with

```
@model ParentViewModel
....
@Html.Partial("_Partial", Model.Child)
```